# How to extract a JSON field that has a random string with the jq command?

Tags: json, jq

Please bear with me I'm still learning about JSON and programming in general. So I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "root_200888546292191": {
        "fields": {
            "buyerId": "31392191"
        },
        "id": "200718546292191",
        "tag": "root",
        "type": "biz"
    },
    "shippingInfo_#package#OF04472002179150#WAREHOUSE_ACCEPTED": {
        "fields": {
            "delivery": {
                "createdAt": "Sen 09 Apr - Rab 11 Apr",
                "desc": "Standar",
                "email": null,
                "method": "Standard",
                "status": "info"
            },
            "statusMap": {
                "active": "Dalam proses",
                "all": ["Dalam proses", "Dalam pengiriman", "Telah diterima"]
            },
            "trackingList": [{
                "info": "Status One",
                "updatedAt": "05 Apr 2018 - 11:00"
            }, {
                "info": "Status Two",
                "updatedAt": "05 Apr 2018 - 11:00"
            }]
        },
        "id": "#package#OF04472002179150#WAREHOUSE_ACCEPTED",
        "tag": "shippingInfo",
        "type": "biz"
    },
    "shippingInfo_#package#AAAAAAAAAAAAA#NOT_WAREHOUSE_ACCEPTED": {
        "fields": {
            "delivery": {
                "createdAt": "Sen 09 Apr - Rab 11 Apr",
                "desc": "Standar",
                "email": null,
                "method": "Standard",
                "status": "info"
            },
            "statusMap": {
                "active": "Dalam proses",
                "all": ["Dalam proses", "Dalam pengiriman", "Telah diterima"]
            },
            "trackingList": [{
                "info": "Status Three",
                "updatedAt": "05 Apr 2018 - 11:00"
            }, {
                "info": "Status Four",
                "updatedAt": "05 Apr 2018 - 11:00"
            }]
        },
        "id": "#package#AAAAAAAAAAAAA#NOT_WAREHOUSE_ACCEPTED",
        "tag": "shippingInfo",
        "type": "biz"
    },
    "login_200718577292191": {
        "fields": {
            "buyerEmail": "myemail@gmail.com",
            "buyerName": "myname"
        },
        "id": "200718522292191",
        "tag": "login",
        "type": "biz"
    }
}
```

And I want to extract `Info` in `shippingInfo_` > `fields` > `trackingList` So the output that I want is like this:

```
Status One
Status Two
Status Three
Status Four
```

The string after `shippingInfo_` is always random, how do I extract it with jq?

This is as far as I've got `jq '.shippingInfo_*.fields.trackingList.info'`

Comment: If you're the one designing the data structure I would recommend not having that parameter name conatain random characters.

Comment: I'm not .............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Direct approaches

There are many direct approaches, e.g.:

#### Using `paths`

```
paths as $p
| select( $p|length == 5 and
         ($p[0] | startswith("shippingInfo_")) and
         $p[1:3] == ["fields", "trackingList"] and
         $p[4] == "info")
| getpath($p)
```

#### Using `to_entries`

```
to_entries[]
| select(.key |  startswith("shippingInfo_"))
| .value
| .fields.trackingList[]
| .info
```

### Indirect approaches

There are also some indirect approaches that are worth mentioning, e.g.

#### Using a helper function

```
def dot(s):
  to_entries[] | select(.key|test(s)) | .value ;

dot("^shippingInfo_")
| .fields.trackingList[]
| .info
```

The last-mentioned filter can be abbreviated to:

```
dot("^shippingInfo_").fields.trackingList[].info
```

### Relaxed requirements

If it is acceptable to ignore the "^shippingInfo_" requirement, the following may be worth considering as well:

```
.[].fields.trackingList[]?.info
```

or even:

```
.. | objects.fields.trackingList[]?.info
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I only want to extract the first values of `info` ? So the output should only be `Status One Status Three`

Comment: In the first case, add a requirement that $p[3] == 0; and so on.

Comment: How do I do it with your second solution `to_entries` ? Your second solution is more understandable for me, instead of the first one

Comment: You could, for example, replace .fields.trackingList[] by  `first(.fields.trackingList[])`